# React Native using NativeBase - Is it possible to show and customize an array with multiple data sets inside the Accordion content?

Tags: react-native, native-base

Using NativeBase, I am trying to have the Accordion content display multiple rows of JSX with some JSON data I will be getting later on.

In all the examples I see, content is set to just a simple string but I would like to use it for more.
I can think of another way to do this if this is a limitation to using NativeBase but it seems like something that should be easy to do.

Example data that would be used to populate the Accordion:

```
  { title: "First Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  { title: "Second Element", content: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" },
  {
    title: "Third Element",
    content: {
      description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      moreInfoItems: [
        { Item1: 1, Item2: 10, Item3: 225, Item4: 90 },
        { Item1: 2, Item2: 20, Item3: 325, Item4: 100 }
      ]
    }
  }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it can, you can use the `renderContent` method to render the special content format data.

```
...
<Accordion
            dataArray={dataArray}
            animation={true}
            expanded={true}
            renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
            renderContent={this._renderContent}
          />
...

_renderContent(item){
   // typeof can tell function,string array, object ..
   if( typeof(item.content) == "string")
  {
      return (<Text>{item.content}</Text>)
   }
   // if it is a json or array
    return (<Text
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "#e3f1f1",
          padding: 10,
          fontStyle: "italic",
        }}
      >
        {item.content.description}
      </Text>)
}
```

what content you want to show, you can according to your situation to define